# phpMyAdmin automatically running odd query when clicking browse table

Tags: phpmyadmin

I've run into this once in the last 4 years and it popped up again.  I can't remember how to fix it.

Normally when you click BROWSE on a table the query is

```
SELECT * from table_name
```

For some odd reason, one of my tables is running this query

```
SELECT * FROM `table_name` ORDER BY `column_name` ASC LIMIT 0, 25
```

It's binding that query and driving me nuts. Does anybody know how to switch it back to the default query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Navigate to Server -> Settings -> Main Panel -> Browse Mode -> "Default sorting order"
Change this setting to SMART (i.e. descending order for columns of type TIME, DATE, DATETIME and TIMESTAMP, ascending order otherwise.)

With this, on the same page navigate to "Remember table's sorting" and uncheck the checkbox.